# Using config driven logic in createCriteria grails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have requirement in which i need some logic of criteria query to be config driven. Earlier i used to query like :
e.g.:

```
User.createCriteria().list{
     or{ 
        eq('username',user.username)
        eq('name',user.name)
     }
}
```

But, i need this to be configurable in my use case so, i try this code snippet.

```
def criteriaCondition= grailsApplication.config.criteriaCondition?:{user->
         or{
           eq('username',user.username)
           eq('name',user.name)   
         }
}

User.createCriteria().list{criteriaCondition(user)}
```

But, This doesn't work for me. I am getting missing method exception for "or" I tried few solution from some sources but it didn't worked for me.

So, can anyone help me :

1) How to make the above given code work.
2) Any other better way for my use case.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Does it work if you try: `User.createCriteria().list grailsApplication.config.criteriaCondition ?: { user-> eq('username',user.username) }`

Comment: No it gives me null pointer exception "can't call username on null object"...How can i pass user to this closure? because i might need to pass more values.

Comment: what does `grailsApplication.config.criteriaCondition` look like?

Comment: It is closure which can have few parameters and series of condition on  the domain. like i mention or{eq() le()...}

Comment: So it has different parameters to the `{ user ->` block?

Comment: yes, according to the need i might need to pass few objects to the closure For exam: {obj1,obj2-> } that is why i want to make this config driven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to pass criteriaBuilder object to the closure, something like this:

```
def criteriaCondition = grailsApplication.config.criteriaCondition ?: { cb, user ->
     cb.or{
       cb.eq('username',user.username)
       cb.eq('name',user.name)   
     }
}

def criteriaBuilder = User.createCriteria()

criteriaBuilder.list{
    criteriaCondition(criteriaBuilder, user)
}
```

obviously, closure in the Config.groovy also has to have the same parameters list, including `cb`

Comment: Any other better way for my use case?

Answer (score 2):

The way the criteria builder mechanism works, the `list` method expects to be passed a closure which it will call, whereas your current code is calling the `criteriaCondition` closure itself rather than letting the criteria builder call it.  "Currying" will help you here: given

```
def criteriaCondition= grailsApplication.config.criteriaCondition?:{user->
         or{
           eq('username',user.username)
           eq('name',user.name)   
         }
}
```

instead of saying

```
User.createCriteria().list{criteriaCondition(user)}
```

you say

```
User.createCriteria().list(criteriaCondition.curry(user))
```

(note the round brackets rather than braces).

The `curry` method of `Closure` returns you another `Closure` with some or all of its arguments "pre-bound" to specific values.  For example

```
def add = {a, b -> a + b}
def twoPlus = add.curry(2) // gives a closure equivalent to {b -> 2 + b}
println twoPlus(3) // prints 5
```

In your case, `criteriaCondition.curry(user)` gives you a zero-argument closure that you can pass to `criteria.list`.  You can curry as many arguments as you like (up to the number that the closure can accept).